# Connect from Postgres to sql server

Tags: postgresql

I want to Connect from Postgres to sql server and fetch some data from a sql table to postgres.

I searched on internet and i found db_link but it is connecting only from postgres server to another postgres but not to my sql server and getting data from sql to postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are one time solutions like: [DB-Sync](https://dbconvert.com/postgresql/mysql/)

If you want to sync the data more than once and periodically or event-driven, I highly recommend a custom script. E.g. a php-cronjob.

Comment: Hi Doomenik,
Thanks for the response. That is helpful. I have a another requirement here.
On the button click from the user we are calling postgre function. So from postgres function i want to call sql data base. Is there any way to do it

Comment: @HemanthVatti There are possibilities on an enterprise level (Postgress notify + some listening daemon), it would be way easier if you either run on a button click a Postgres and a SQL function or modify the function to simply do both. In most use cases the sql statement is identically between postgres and sql so most likely you only have to modify the chosen DB + table.